# Understanding the large curly brace in a statement about absolute value

Tags: notation, absolute-value

I'm trying to learn from the book *A First Course in Calculus* by Serge Lang, but I don't know how to interpret the large curly brace after the absolute value of $a$:

> **Theorem 2.1.** If $a$ is any number, then
> $$|a| = \begin{cases} 
> \phantom{-}a & \text{if}\; a\geq 0 \\
> -a & \text{if}\; a < 0 \end{cases} $$

I don't know what the correct name for it either, so I didn't know what to search for.

> So, how do I spell this theorem out in sentenced English?

I'm thinking that might help me understand it better.

Comment: The absolute value of $a$ is $a$ if $a$ is non-negative and $-a$ if $a$ is negative.

Comment: The phrase you're looking for is probably ["piecewise function"](https://www.google.com/search?q=piecewise+function) (also "piecewise defined function" is used). The curly braces are a standard way of giving formulas for them.

Comment: As noted in [@Brian's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4079106/409), that's the standard way of expressing conditional "cases" in an equation. FYI: The TeX markup for the structure is, fittingly, `\begin{cases} ... \end{cases}` (which I used in editing your question to transcribe the quote from the image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a definition by cases; here the cases are $(1)$ $a\ge 0$ and $(2)$ $a<0$. Thus, it means that if $a\ge 0$, then $|a|=a$, and if $a<0$, then $|a|=-a$.

This is a very standard way of expressing a definition by cases; you are likely to see it over and over again.